# Systems of equations of the form $\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J_i} v_i \times v_j = a$

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, tensor-products, cross-product

Is there any theory that deals (directly or not) with systems of equations of the form 
$$\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J_i} v_i \times v_j = a,$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is known, $v_i, v_j \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are unknowns, and $\times$ denotes the cross product? $I$ and $J_i$ are sets of indices, with $J_i$ depending on $i$.

Comment: I think you should specify that $i<j$ or something like that in order not to make the sum trivial.

Comment: When "everything" is possible, $v_i\times v_j$ and $v_j\times v_i$ always occur, then they kill each other out. Thus, the sum is 0.

Comment: I think the absense of restrictions on the indices indicates that "everything" is possible there; that is, we may have $i = j$ or not. Of course, the products $v_i \times v_i$ don't matter. But there are other.

Comment: But $i$ and $j$ may range different values. Is it not clear?

Comment: I have edited the question with different names for the ranges of the indices for $i$ and $j$ (which may be not disjoint).

Comment: Are you inquiring where this would come up? If so, you can look into Continuum Mechanics.

Comment: It's nice to know that it appears in continuum mechanics. Could you indicate some reference? But i'm especially wondering whether there is some theory that provides methods of solving these systems.